# NSUUID conflict (iOS6.0 and Above)

Tags: objective-c, ios

We have a NSUUID class (we provide the declaration and implementation). We used it successfully up to iOS 6.0. We implemented it because `UIDevice uniqueIdentifier` was banned long before Apple deprecated it, and returning a NSUUID was a natural choice.

At iOS 6.0, we had to guard the define because Apple introduced the same class:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED <= __IPHONE_5_1
@interface NSUUID : NSObject {
    ...
}
#endif
```

iOS 5.1 and lesser are now broken. On iOS 5.1, we get back `nil` after `alloc/init`.

I tried to remove the `#if/#end`, but I get duplicate names when using the latest iPhone SDK.

Apple's lack of a stable API is a bug, not a feature. This "try it at runtime" crap is not cutting it. It makes it very difficult to write high integrity software.

From Tommy's response below, I can't instruct Apple's toolchain to use our implementation of NSUUID all the time. How do I provide an implementation of NSUUID for iOS 5.1 and lower (that might be compiled using the latest SDK)?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just rename NSUUID for your next release? Your users will have to update anyway because their binary will conflict with their OS if they try to update their iOS.

Comment: This exhibits a case where Objective-C namespace collision occurred. Perhaps the unwise use of Apple-reserved NS-prefix was to blame.

Comment: I want this to work everywhere: `NSUUID* uuid = [DeviceUtils applicationIdentifier]`. That only works if there is a `NSUUID` available on all platforms. On iOS 5.1 and lesser, we *hove* to provide it because its missing. There was no choice in the matter.

Comment: @noloader If you want to support iOS 5.x, _don't use iOS 6 APIs_. You've already written your own UUID class, just use it everywhere. Name your class something else (you shouldn't be using the NS prefix anyway) and be done with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. You've explicitly broken [the rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html):

> Objective-C classes must be named uniquely [...] In order to keep
>   class names unique, the convention is to use prefixes on all classes.
>   You’ll have noticed that Cocoa and Cocoa Touch class names typically
>   start either with NS or UI. Two-letter prefixes like these are
>   reserved by Apple for use in framework classes.

You'll need to rename your own class. The quickest way is quite probably to right click on the class name, select "Refactor -> Rename..." and use a correct prefix this time. Xcode may not be able to refactor fully automatically since it'll obviously be ambiguous which `NSUUID` you're referring to in other parts of your code.

EDIT: regardless of grandstanding, if you want to implement code that provides a self-implemented replacement for `NSUUID` where it's not available then the solution is to "try it at runtime".

Assuming you've implemented `NDRUUID`, which implements the same interface as `NSUUID` then the quickest solution is to add something like this to your prefix header:

```
#define NSUUID (NSClassFromString(@"NSUUID") ? [NSUUID class] : [NDRUUID class])
```

You can then use `[NSUUID UUID]`, etc, everywhere else in your code as though you were targeting iOS 6 only; the only difference is that when running under 5 you'll actually be addressing `NDRUUID`. Whenever you stop supporting 5 just remove that line from your prefix header and delete your own class from the project.

Hopefully you can see this is a much better way to handle introducing new APIs and backwards compatibility than, say, not using Apple's NSUUID at all anywhere until it's available everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy. It does not help us in all cases (iOS 6.0 and above, and iOS 5.1 and lower). Let me rephrase: how do I provide an implementation of NSUUID for iOS 5.1 and lower (that might be compiled using the latest SDK).

Comment: Tommy already answered your question. Rename the class. That will work on all versions of iOS.

Comment: @erurainon - Actually, it won't. iOS 5.1 clients don't have NSUUID. So it will fail.

Comment: The point is just use the newly named class every time. If you want to use NSUUID for iOS 6, then just check for it's existence at runtime.

Comment: I've updated in case what you want to do is reimplement NSUUID with exactly the same interface so that you can use it as per Apple's documentation under both 5 and 6 via a crutch that you can pull away when version support next ebbs. If you're just looking to have a UUID provider of your own invention, don't call it NSUUID.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy. Last question. Mach-O uses fat binaries. Is it possible to include our NSUUID code for iOS 5.1 and lesser (assuming the link/loader will do the right thing at runtime)? Is this even supported? And why is NSUUID not a weak symbol?

Comment: @noloader as far as I'm aware, fat binaries can distinguish based on the processor only, not the OS version. And there's only a very weak correlation between the three architectures Apple has used in iOS to date and OS versions.

Answer (score 2):

I have built exactly what you asked for: an implementation of `NSUUID` for iOS 5.1 and lower that might be compiled using the latest SDK. See my [NSUUID](https://github.com/0xced/NSUUID) project on GitHub.